# Which Javascript WYSIWYG editor produces the cleanest/SEO-friendliest output?

Tags: javascript, editor, wysiwyg, seo

I  have been looking into javascript wysiwyg text editors for use on a topicality website.
SEO friendliness is obviously very important because the site aims to attract visitors looking for articles on recent events in their particular niche.

TinyMCE uses tables for formatting and NicEdit or CKEditor don't seem to have any demo's that show output. It would be great if someone who has used these - or others - before could comment on this aspect or make a recommendation.

The solution doesn't have to be really lightweight or extremely accessible as it will only be used by the editorial staff, not the users. It also doesn't really need to support any wild formatting, basic text mark-up and images would suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been using FCKEditor for a while, now it seems to be renamed to CKEditor. You may find it [here](http://ckeditor.com/). It has been a year already, hope they didn't get worse.

I really liked to possibility to fully customize the panel tool (I enabled just the url, bold, italic and some lists probably, pretty much what stackoverflow has). As far as I remember the output code was quite ok in the terms of clean html.

**EDIT:** example output from FCKEditor for very basic posts using list, strong, italic and hrefs:

```
<p>Hele tak</p>
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com"><strong>tady</strong></a></li>
    <li>jen tat<br />
    gfe</li>
</ul>
<p><em>konec</em></p>
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't noice you already mentioned CKEditor in your post.

Comment: I'm still interested in your experience with FCKEditor. Does it produce reasonably clean output ?

Comment: I remember when I was choosing the editor the clean output was one of the biggest drivers for my decision. Its true that I needed only simple stuff like I wrote and that was really ok. Not sure how would it be with something more complicated like tables etc. Let me check my sources for an example ...

Comment: Definitely looks better than what TinyMCE promised. I imagine the output in CKEditor has to be at least as good so I'll be trying that out. Thanks for your answer !

Comment: No problem, if you will have a minute it will be nice to hear a update on CKEditor. My version is probably a bit out of date :)

Comment: I'm not yet up to the point of implementation, but I did find a demo that shows you the generated output after submit [over here](http://nightly.ckeditor.com/6559/_samples/output_html.html). The customization options look pretty promising.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [Dreamweaver](http://www.adobe.com/de/products/dreamweaver/whatsnew/?sdid=IBFBF&)? Its easy, nice and enables working with code or drag and drop as you prefer. But im not very sure regarding SEO.

Comment: I'm sorry, my question wasn't clear enough. I should have specified I was looking for a javascript wysiwyg **text** editor to place on the website. Much like the one on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Parusa, perhaps similar to the one on Reddit? Their source is open, so you might see what they use.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I don't think I have the ambition to dig into Reddit's code at the moment. If I get to a point where none of the popular solutions meet my requirements I'll look into it.